# Why do we need to use import 'babel-polyfill'; in react components?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux

I wonder if we user babel loader + all the presets, why do we need to include babel-polyfill anyway into our components? I just think that babel-loader should do all the job itself.

Examples were taken here https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples

What i am asking about is:

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import App from './containers/App';
```

Here is package example:

```
{
  "name": "redux-shopping-cart-example",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Redux shopping-cart example",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test mocha --recursive --compilers js:babel-register",
    "test:watch": "npm test -- --watch"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/reactjs/redux.git"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "http://redux.js.org",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.3.14",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
    "react-redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux": "^3.2.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^1.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.3.15",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.1.1",
    "cross-env": "^1.0.7",
    "enzyme": "^2.0.0",
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.3",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^0.14.7",
    "redux-logger": "^2.0.1",
    "mocha": "^2.2.5",
    "node-libs-browser": "^0.5.2",
    "webpack": "^1.9.11",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.2.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.9.1"
  }
}
```

Here is webpack config example taken from https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loaders: [ 'babel?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015,presets[]=react-hmre' ],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: __dirname
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loaders: [ 'json' ],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: __dirname
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Babel transpiles your code to something that browsers can understand, but the resulting code uses features that may or may not work in every single browser. For example `Object.assign` is not supported in all browsers, so babel-polyfill fills the holes. It's just a collection of polyfills that you would usually include anyway to have support for legacy browsers.

Consider this code:

```
const foo = {
  name: 'Homer'
};
const bar = Object.assign({}, foo, {age: '?'});
console.log(Object.keys(foo), Object.keys(bar));
```

Babel will transpile this to the almost identical:

```
'use strict';
var foo = {
  name: 'Homer'
};
var bar = Object.assign({}, foo, { age: '?' });
console.log(Object.keys(foo), Object.keys(bar));
```

because this is normal old school JS syntax. However, that doesn't mean that the native functions used are implemented in all browsers, so we need to include the polyfill.

Comment: If i would any transpiler developer i would think like this: 
Ok -> i need make let from var, yep? Yep! Next thing, ok i want to make function that adds the same functionality which Object.assign has. Isn't it expected behavior? So if Object.assign is in es6, transpiler (or preset) should care of this. If it exist in es7, es7 preset should care of this. Not additional module that even not a transpiler which should sit in each file i have. Lets do additional modules for let -> var replacement then as well. Hope anyone will agree with me that it make sense. Thanks for an explanation by the way.

Comment: Well, polyfills have been around forever, because IE, Chrome, Firefox etc don't have the same functionality implemented. Babel only handles stuff like arrow functions, imports, const, etc, but generally doesn't touch the js API functions. If you need to support IE9 or whatever, that isn't something Babel should care about. It just creates javascript that follows traditional patterns, the functions used however is your job to polyfill _if needed_.